# Form correct SQL query using SQLDatabaseChain

Tags: prompt, agent, langchain, large-language-model, azure-openai

I have a transaction table in my database. I want to use `SQLDatabaseChain` to form a query and retrieve the answer from database. One of the column in my database is `location`, and the values in the column is `Luke Pyramid`,`Hong Qing Road`,etc...

Now, I'm asking the chatbot the following question:

`What is the sales in year 2023 at Luke?`

The Query formed is:

`SELECT SUM(sales) FROM transaction_table WHERE year = '2023' AND location = 'Luke';`

Based on the query above, obviously there is no data because the location is `Luke Pyramid` instead of `Luke`. But as a user of the chatbot, sometime they will call the location as `Luke` instead of `Luke Pyramid`, and hence cause the query to fail.

May I know is there any way to solve this problem? Not sure how should I modify the prompt template to achieve my goal. Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: could you try query like "What is the sales in year 2023 in city like Luke ?"